# Segmentation fault with PyType_IsSubtype

Tags: python-c-extension

I'm getting the following error when debugging a C extension in gdb

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
PyType_IsSubtype (a=0xc0089ca71d1afbb6, b=0x7fffed5441e0) at Objects/typeobject.c:1150
1150    Objects/typeobject.c: No such file or directory.
        in Objects/typeobject.c
```

All I've found about it, so far, was a bug report regarding Python 3.4 in Debian 6.

Using: Python 2.7.6/CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved. On my C extension code I was creating some objects:

```
PyArrayObject *py_u2r, *py_u2l, *py_u2s;

py_u2r= (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FromDims(2,dims,NPY_CDOUBLE);
py_u2l= (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FromDims(2,dims,NPY_CDOUBLE);
py_u2s= (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_FromDims(2,dims,NPY_CDOUBLE);
```

Only problem was that I wasn't returning them properly. So, I just added following return line and it is working now:

```
return Py_BuildValue("OOO", py_u2r, py_u2l, py_u2s);
```

In this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) I figured out about `Py_BuildValue` syntax, which is pretty straightforward.